# A sufficient condition for the composition of covering maps to be a covering map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> Let $q:X \rightarrow Y$ and $r:Y \rightarrow Z$ be covering maps and $p= r  \circ q$. If $r^{-1}(z)$ is finite for all $z \in Z$, then $p$ is a covering map.

Now I found the following proof:

> Let $z \in U_z$ where $U_z$ is some open set that is evenly covered by $r$.
>
> Let $\{V_1,...,V_k\}$ be a partition of slices with $y_i \in V_i$ with $r(y_i)=z$. Then there exists for all $y_i$ an open set $W_i$ that is evenly covered by $q$ and without loss of generality $W_i \subset V_i$.
> Set $U :=r(W_1) \cap...\cap r(W_k)$ which is open in $Z$, due to the fact that covering maps are open, then $U$ is evenly covered by $p$.

I don't get it why $U$ works. I mean, it is not that clear to me why $r^{-1}(U) \subset W_i$? But we should have $r^{-1}(U) \subset W_i$ in order to be sure that $r^{-1}(U)$ is evenly covered by $q$.

Comment: But $r^{-1}(r(U))$ not make sense. $U$ is a subset of $Z$, and $r:Y\to Z$.

Comment: you are right, I had a typo in there.

Comment: Also I think that $r^{-1}(U)\subset \cup_iW_i$,, because if is it, we have $r^{-1}(U)\subset\cap_iW_i\subset \cap_i V_i=\emptyset$.

Comment: By construction, $r^{-1}(U) \cap V_i \subset W_i$. Since $r^{-1}(U) \subset r^{-1}(U_z) = \bigcup V_i$, it follows that $r^{-1}(U) \subset \bigcup W_i$. Happiness.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308490/composition-of-certain-covering-maps?rq=1