# Showing whether a certain subset is evenly covered by a map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am stuck in problem 53.4 from Munkres: **Let $ q : X \to Y $ and $ r : Y \to Z $ be covering maps; let $ p = r \circ q $. Show that if $ r^{-1}(z) $ is finite for each $ z \in Z $, then $ p $ is a covering map.**

This is my work so far:

> First, $ p $ is both continuous and surjective, because the
>   composition of continuous/surjective maps is again
>   continuous/surjective (note that both $ r $ and $ q $ are continuous
>   and surjective, since they are covering maps).
>
> Let $ z \in Z $.
>   Since $ r $ is a covering map, there exists an open neighborhood $ U $
>   of $ z $ that is evenly covered by $ r $. For all $ y \in r^{-1}(z) $,
>   there exists an open neighborhood $ V_{y} $ of $ y $ that is evenly
>   covered by $ q $, since $ q $ is a covering map. We now define 
>   \begin{align*} U' := \bigcap_{y \in r^{-1}(z)} r(V_{y}) \end{align*}
>   We claim that $ U' $ is both open and evenly covered by $ p $, making
>   $ p $ a covering map (since for all elements of $ Z $, a corresponding
>   $ U' $ can be constructed).
>
> $ U' $ is open in $ Z $ because it is a
>   finite intersection of finitely many open subsets $ r(V_{y}) $, as $ r^{-1}(z) $ is finite. Each $ r(V_{y}) $ is open in $ Z $ because the
>   covering map $ r $ is open. Since each $ V_{y} $ is
>   open, it follows that $ r(V_{y}) $ is open.      We now show that $ U' $
>   is evenly covered my $ p $, that is, $ p^{-1}(U') $ is a union of
>   disjoint open sets in $ X $.

I am stuck in showing whether $p^{-1}(U')$ can be expressed as a disjoint union of open sets in $X$, each of which is homeomorphic to $U'$. Is it true that my $U'$ is evenly covered by $p$?

Comment: not necessarily, you should start by an evenly covered neighbourhood of $z$, see my answer.

Comment: Your $U'$ should be intersected with $U$ as well. You need to keep the properties of $U$. Then you get the same set I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity and surjectivity are clear, as you state. The work is in the evenly covered part of the definition:

Take a fixed $z \in Z$. This has the points $y_1, \ldots y_n$ (for some finite $n$ by assumption) as preimages in $Y$ and an evenly covered open neighbourhood $U_z$ such that for every $i=1,\ldots,n$ we have open $V_i$ pairwise disjoint and containing $y_i$ such that $r|_{V_i}$ is a homeomorphism between $V_i$ and $U_z$.

Now each $y_i$ likewise has an evenly covered (for $q$) neighbourhood $W_{y_i}$.
We can now replace $U_z$ by the better neighbourhood $U'_z:= \cap_{i=1}^n r[W_{y_i} \cap V_i]$ (which is open as a finite intersection of open sets). $U'_z$ is still evenly covered by $r$ but now the $y_i$ disjoint neighbourhoods are $W_{y_i} \cap V_i$ (and these in turn are *still* evenly covered by $q$).

You can now easily check that $U'_z$ is the required evenly covered neighbourhood for $p$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309133/4280) for this same idea with slightly more details, which I found later.

Comment: Is it then true that the preimage under $q$ of the disjoint neighbourhoods $W_{y_{i}} \cap V_{i}$ is a disjoint union of subsets of $X$? If yes, why?

Comment: @fcm Yes, because this holds for $W_{y_i}$. Say, $q^{-1}[W_{y_i}]$ is a disjoint union of $O_j, j \in J$ then $q^{-1}[W_{y_i} \cap V_i]$ is a disjoint union of $O_j \cap q^{-1}[V_i]$ etc.

Comment: I apologize for my wording, but I meant to ask if the preimage of the collection of disjoint sets $W_{y_{i}}∩V_{i}$ is a disjoint union of subsets of $X$. In other words, why is $ (q^{-1} \circ r^{-1})(U_{z}') $ a disjoint union of subsets of $ X $?

Comment: @fcm that's clear. They're just all the sets $q^{-1}[V_i] \cap O_j$ where $i=1\ldots,n$ and $j \in I_i$.

Comment: where $O_j, j \in I_i$ is the disjoint decomposition of $q^{-1}[W_{y_i}]$. plus a composition of homeomorphisms is a homeomorpism etc.